# Логические операторы по книге о Питоне Марка Саммерфильда

Tags: python

Всем привет. Читаю книгу по Питону Марка Саммерфильда. Не могу понять одну вещь, касающуюся логических операторов (40-41 стр.). Почему в коде в *IDLE* такие результаты. Какой тут принцип? И почему ни `true`, ни `false` выводится. Всем спасибо.

```
>>>> five = 5

>>>> two = 2

>>>> zero = 0

>>>> five and two

2
>>>> two and five

5
>>>> five and zero

0
```

Answer (score 5):

Потому что

> Если у and оба операнда являются истиной, результатом будет последнее значение

Соответственно у Вас нету значений `0`, `''`, `[]`, `()`, `{}` и `None`, которые являются ложью - значит оба операнда - истина.

В последнем примере:

> Если какой-либо из операндов является ложью, результатом будет первое такое значение

**[Источник](http://ru.diveintopython.net/apihelper_andor.html)**

Если же Вы всё таки хотите видеть `True` или `False` воспользуйтесь методом `bool(two and five)`

[bool documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.3/whatsnew/section-bool.html)

Answer (score -1):

```
# left and right
# вернет left,  при bool(left) is False, иначе right

# left or right
# вернет right, при bool(left) is False, иначе left
```